# how to make a different conditions with one input (python)

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi, rfid

Can anyone help me with this coding?

I want to insert a RFID card data to a MySQL database.
When i first tap the tag on RFID Reader, the program will insert the data to Masuk table When i tap the tag again, the program will insert the data to Keluar table.

Am i doing right with this code?

```
import MFRC522 
import signal
import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                user='root',
                passwd='12345678',
                db='pa')<br>
cursor = db.cursor()

continue_reading = True
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

cardA = [131,89,173,1,118]

def read ():
    read = 1

def end_read(signal, frame):


global continue_reading
  continue_reading = False
  print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
  MIFAREReader.GPIO_CLEEN()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

while continue_reading:
  (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
  if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
    print "Card detected"
  (status,backData) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()
  if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
    print "Card read UID: "+str(backData[0])+""+str(backData[1])+""+str(backData$
    if backData == cardA:
        print "Selamat Datang Dheny"
        if (read == True):
            sql = """ INSERT INTO Masuk(Nama, No_ID, datetime) VALUES ('Dheny', $
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
        except:
            db.rollback()
        read = False
        if (read == False):
                sql = """ INSERT INTO Keluar(Nama, No_ID, datetime) VALUES ('Dhe$
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
        except:
            db.rollback()
        read = True
```

Comment: i don't know how you keeping the track of tap .simply keep a count of taps ,if it's 1 then insert to masuk or if 2 ,3,4 do whatever you want

Comment: I would try to make it set a var to keep track of taps.

Comment: how to do that? keeping the track of tap?
i mean count the taps? @PavneetSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the code to access and modify the global variable

```
global count 


def modi():
    global count # required to modify the global copy
    count=10

def printc():
    if (count==10): # read it as a normal variable 
        print("yes")


modi()
printc()
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is something like this.create a global variable(count) to achieve the behavior with `if and elif` condition like

```
  if (count==True):
      # insert into musak and update count to false
  elif(count==False):
      # insert into other table and update count to True
```

i don't know if you are try to achieve the behavior with `read` variable if yes then it should be global and use `elif` instead of `if` to execute only one case and you need to change it's value of `read` like following.

```
  if (read == True):
    sql = """ INSERT INTO Masuk(Nama, No_ID, datetime) VALUES ('Dheny', $
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
    global read     # Needed to modify global copy of read 
    globvar = False      # next time read==False case will be executed    
  elif (read == False):
    global read     # Needed to modify global copy of read 
    read = True        # next time read==True case will be executed        
    sql = """ INSERT INTO Keluar(Nama, No_ID, datetime) VALUES ('Dhe$
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro :D.
i'll test it now.